# Silex subdirectory routing behind nginx+lighttpd+rewrite

Tags: nginx, routes, reverse-proxy, lighttpd, silex

I have the following setup: A lighttpd server with mod_fcgi for PHP behind an nginx server acting as a reverse proxy. The lighttpd root dir is mapped to the "my-tool" subdirectory of nginx. I can add rewrite rules in the lighttpd configuration, but can't touch nginx.

I've defined the following rule in my lighttpd conf:

```
url.rewrite-once += (
    "^/my-tool(/[^\?]*)(\?.*)?" => "/index.php$1$2"
)
```

When I request the path `http://example.com/my-tool/bar` in the browser, Silex throws a `NotFoundHttpException` because it can't find `/my-tool/bar` - but the requested route should be `/bar`

What's the best/most standard way to remove the `/my-tool` prefix? Can I do it in the lighttpd config? Do I have to subclass `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` to use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` in `getInfoPath`? Or do I use a "dirty hack" and just remove it from the `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URI']` variable before initializing Silex?

Here are the relevant variables from `$_SERVER`:

```
[ORIG_PATH_TRANSLATED] => /data/project/my-tool/public_html/bar
[ORIG_SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /data/project/my-tool/public_html/index.php/bar
[HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URI] => /my-tool/bar
[REDIRECT_URI] => /index.php/bar
[REQUEST_URI] => /my-tool/bar
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /data/project/my-tool/public_html
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /data/project/my-tool/public_html/index.php
[PATH_TRANSLATED] => /data/project/my-tool/public_html/bar
[PATH_INFO] => /bar
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[PHP_SELF] => /index.php/bar
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? And are you by any chance trying to configure a tool on Wikimedia tool labs? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the full path to `index.php` on the relative-URL side, e.g.:

```
url.rewrite-once += (
  "^/my-tool(/.*)" => "/my-tool/index.php$1"
)
```